# OpenTK C# Perspective Lighting looks glitchy

Tags: c#, opengl, perspective, lighting, opentk

**My goal is to make lighting in perspective view smooth.** I'm using the same light settings for both perspective and orthographic. The images below show that the orthographic lighting looks great. **The perspective lighting looks glitchy and flickers when I rotate it.** What am I missing that would make the perspective view lighting look okay?

**Processor: AMD FX 6100 6-core 3.31GHz**

**Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6800**

Note: I referenced from an OpenGL example. I was playing with the different light settings to find out how they work. The code I pasted at the end of this post is the code that created the images.

Perspective: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSXul.png

Orthographic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7Yr2.png

**Here is the relevant code within my paint method.**

```
private void glControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (!glLoaded)
        return;

    GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
    //GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

    //SET PERSPECTIVE OR ORTHOGRAPHIC VIEW
    if (chkPerspective.Checked)
    {
        double aspect = glControl1.Width / (double)glControl1.Height;

        Matrix4 perspective = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, (float)aspect, 0.0001f, 5000.0f);
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.LoadIdentity();
        GL.LoadMatrix(ref perspective);

        Matrix4 lookat = Matrix4.LookAt(eyeOffset.X, eyeOffset.Y, eyeOffset.Z, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        GL.LoadMatrix(ref lookat);


        //GL.Translate(-boxOffset);
    }
    else
    {
        setupViewPort(); //Orthographic settings
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview); 
        GL.LoadIdentity();
    }

    GL.Rotate(angleY, 1.0f, 0, 0);
    GL.Rotate(angleX, 0, 1.0f, 0);

    //LIGHTING
    if (chkLighting.Checked)
    {
        float[] mat_specular = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
        float[] mat_shininess = { 50.0f };
        float[] light_position = { 1000.0f, 1000.0f, 1000.0f, 100.0f };
        float[] light_ambient = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };

        GL.ClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        //GL.ShadeModel(ShadingModel.Smooth);

        //GL.Material(MaterialFace.Front, MaterialParameter.Specular, mat_specular);
        //GL.Material(MaterialFace.Front, MaterialParameter.Shininess, mat_shininess);
        GL.Light(LightName.Light0, LightParameter.Position, light_position);
        //GL.Light(LightName.Light0, LightParameter.Ambient, light_ambient);
        //GL.Light(LightName.Light0, LightParameter.Diffuse, mat_specular);

        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Lighting);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Light0);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.ColorMaterial);
        //GL.Enable(EnableCap.CullFace);
    }
    else
    {
        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Lighting);
        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Light0);
    }

    foreach (Cube cube in cubes)
    {
        cube.drawCube(selectionCubeRadius);
    }

    glControl1.SwapBuffers();
}
```

**Here is my orthographic viewport code in case it matters.**

```
private void setupViewPort()
{
    if (chkPerspective.Checked)
        return;

    int w = glControl1.Width;
    int h = glControl1.Height;
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
    GL.LoadIdentity();
    GL.Ortho(-w, w, -h, h, -5000, 5000); // Bottom-left corner pixel has coordinate (0, 0)
    GL.Viewport(0, 0, w, h); // Use all of the glControl paintingarea
}
```

Comment: Good question that appears to have all the relevant information required to help an expert solve it. I am _definitely not_ that expert; I assure you that you know more about coding this stuff than I do! I just know a good Q when I see one…

Comment: Are you sure you want 100.0f as light_position.w, not 1.0f ?

Comment: Changing the W to 1.0 makes the change in the light intensity from one side of the blocks to the other less noticeable. The flickering in perspective view is still there, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that will work for now. In perspective view, I reduced the size of the cubes from 200.0 to 5.0. Then I moved the camera closer so they appear the same size. Some also said that I should decrease the far Z-plane when I create my perspective field of view.

Reducing the size of my models worked, but I also decreased the distance of the far z-plane for convention purposes. I'll also likely create an algorithm that determines what z-plane distance to use based on my current model size and angle.

User 'dflemstr' asked about my GL.Normal3f calls. The answer is that I have none. What do they do, and are they necessary?

Comment: A normal is a vector of length 1 that points "out of" your surface. Each vertex has a normal. For example, for the top square of your cube, the normals would be (0, 1, 0) for each vertex, because the surface points upward (positive Y). If you don't specify normals, the driver has to guess them, and light calculations will be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Based solely on the images, it looks like depth test is being disabled or some normals are flipped or non-normalized.

What does drawCube do exactly?

Comment: DrawCube() contains GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads), draws the 6 faces of the cube, and then GL.End(). That is all. Is there a way I can make sure that the normals are correct?

Comment: What *are* your `GL.Normal3f` calls at the moment? They must contain vectors of unit length. Just post the code!